# Own custom vector class. Memory reallocation

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management

I want to implement my own simple vector class. This vector should support pushing new elements (of type `T`) even if reserved memory is exhausted. So, I need to allocate a new block of memory, copy elements to it and then free the old memory block.

If I create a block of memory using `new T[]` then I must free it using `delete[]`, which will make constructors of each element in the vector to be called. I don't want that because I think of just copying the old vector using `memcpy()`.

So I came up with a decision to allocate memory using `new char[]` and use *placement new* to fill the array. When I need to reallocate the reserved memory I just use `memcpy()` on that block of memory and then free it using `delete[]`.

Is this a reasonable solution?

Comment: What is the reason to not use std::vector?

Comment: No.  This violates C++'s object model.  If you have C++11 or higher support you can use move operations.  Also note that you can only use `memcpy` on trivially copyable types.  Types like `std::string` can't be `memcpy`ed

Comment: Not constructing an object properly is undefined behaviour. And it will break any code where the class depends on the actual value of `this`, since your memcpy'ed object will still be assuming the value of `this` from the old object.

Comment: Using `memcpy()` has undefined behaviour for types that are not trivially copyable in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only certain objects that should (as in, are allowed to) be "copied" via `memcpy`. These are called [**trivial types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt767760.aspx) - which cannot have custom destructors.

Thus, using `memcpy` to avoid calling destructors is contradictory. You're only allowed to do the former if the latter is unnecessary.

Consider this: In general, a `T` may have pointers/references to its own members (or other `T` in the same vector). If you move these objects around with `memcpy`, these will keep referring to the old (now invalid) memory locations. This is exactly what the constructors and destructors of `T` have to handle (if copying/moving them is even allowed), so omitting them will lead to problems.

Comment: Oh, that was really a stupid question. Thank you for explanation!

Comment: @Nikita On the contrary, the fact that you considered it is not stupid at all. It is pretty fundamental thing about computing/programming in general. It is not specific to C++, only in C++ you encounter it more directly. Other languages just hide it from you performing (sometimes very expensive) reallocations like that without the programmer understanding what is going on. Because there simply is _no_ dynamic array.